# $.getJSON to a php with include_once fails but it did the work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I've a PHP webservice and when I call it with $.getJSON it goes to the .fail callback.

The problem appears only when i do an include_once at PHP. If I copy/paste what the included file does to the main php it works fine.

The responsetext is what I expected (a JSON with the data asked) and the status is 200, but inside the .fail callback.

It's strange. Anyone knows if there's any problems using include_once?

Then piece of PHP code is:

```
$bCarregat = include_once("sql/". $sConsulta .".php");
```

and if i replace it with:

```
$sSqlBase = "SELECT usuari, nom, moduls";
$sSqlBase .= " FROM www_usuari";
$sSqlBase .= " WHERE 1=1";
if (isset($aRestr['USUARI']) AND $aRestr['USUARI'] != "") {
    $sSqlBase .= " AND usuari = '". str_replace("'", "''", $aRestr['USUARI']) ."'";
}
```

it works.

Comment: if `include` were to return the contents, which is doesn't, it would still not work because you are assigning it to a variable. You would have to echo the variable somewhere. But the real issue is as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: no, the variable are to check if the include did include.

Comment: same behavior without assigning to a variable

Comment: What are you doing with `$bCarregat` an  `$x = include_once 'file.php';` returns `1` (one) if the file is included and false if it is not. However it also generates 2 warnngs and a stack dump if it fails

Comment: just to rule out the obvious. Does your included file have PHP begin and end tags? And please remove your answer which is not an answer.

Comment: I use it later to execute or not the function loaded with the include. It can be omitted if cause problems, but omitting it, the same behavior does.

Comment: ok, deleted. checked also begin and end tags: `<?php
 function getSQL($aRestr, &$sError) { 
  /**
   $aRestr:
    Estructura esperada: Array [
     'USUARI'=>Codi usuari a restringir. Si no està informat, carreguem tots els usuaris
  **/
  $sSqlBase = "SELECT usuari, nom, moduls";
  $sSqlBase .= " FROM www_usuari";
  $sSqlBase .= " WHERE 1=1";
  if (isset($aRestr['USUARI']) AND $aRestr['USUARI'] != "") {
   $sSqlBase .= " AND usuari = '". str_replace("'", "''", $aRestr['USUARI']) ."'";
  }
  return $sSqlBase;
 }
?>
`

Comment: the strange thing is that PHP works well (do what i want), but the AJAX response goes to `.fail` instead of `.done`. Debugging the AJAX call, the responsetext has the correct JSON returned from PHP

Comment: Can you show your ajax call code

Comment: that's the ajax call. it goes to .fail if i use include into php and goes to .done if don't: ` $.getJSON(getMBD_URL() +'?Consulta='+ jCRUD.Origen.Consulta +'&Sentencia='+ jCRUD.Origen.Sql +'&UserName='+ sessionStorage.usuari +'&Token='+ sessionStorage.token +'&sFormat=META&Modul='+ sModul_global)
  .fail(
   function(jData) {
    errorGetJSON(jData);
   })
  .done(function(jData) {
.... do something...
});`

Comment: It seems like the include_once is echoing something that breaks the json response structure, but i can't see what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem saving the secondary php file (the included) in UTF-8 **without BOM**.

I didn't know about the existence of different UTF-8 formats, but a little beginning char at response text (\ufeff) made me suspect.

I apreciate all your frustrated attempts to help me ;-P they have not been i vain.